# Implementing a builder using closures in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to implement a builder using closures in JavaScript. I feel it can be done, but am struggling to put it into code.

I have something like this but I feel there is probably a better solution leveraging something like partial application.

```
function Builder() {
    this.spec = {};
}

Builder.prototype.withFoo = function(value) {
    this.spec.foo = value;
    return this;
};

Builder.prototype.withBar = function(value) {
    this.spec.bar = value;
    return this;
};

Builder.prototype.build = function() {
    var result = {};
    result.foo = this.spec.foo;
    result.bar = this.spec.bar;
    this.spec = {}; // This is to avoid accidentally using the same builder repeatedly.

    return result;
};

var builder = new Builder();
builder.withFoo('foo value')
       .withBar('foo value')
       .build(); // { foo: 'foo value' , bar: 'bar value' }
```

Can anyone help me do this?

**Edit:** The key thing here is that I want the object to be instantiated lazily.

Comment: `builder` in `return builder;` is undefined. If you want to return the current instance, use `this` instead. And can you maybe explain, what exact kind of behavior you are trying to achieve? Some people might be able to help but are not familiar with a "builder" pattern or don't know what you mean by "partial application".

Answer (score 6):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
function Builder(obj){
    return obj;
}
```

This is called by Fowler and Martin the "Identity Builder" and is quite common in enterprise architecture. It has the advantage of supporting arbitrarily nested hierarchies of objects and sub objects and it is completely generic.

```
var myBuildObject = Builder({
    spec: { 
        foo: foo,
        bar: bar
    }
});
```

It does so much more though, it can also easily specify arrays:

```
var myBuildObject = Builder({
    spec: [....]
});
```

It can be extended and subclassed with more sophisticated builders that can in turn do `return Builder.call(this, obj)` after decorating it.

It can even specify getters/setters.

Comment: So it's acceptable to supply ironic answers that may mislead newbies?

Comment: @BenAston it's not ironic and it's not misleading. What this answer is (the identity function) is meant as a criticism on why one would implement a builder in JavaScript in the first place - namely, it demonstrates that what you'd use a builder for in a language like Java can be done using a literal in a language like JavaScript. The goal of this answer is to get people to think about why they're using a builder in the first place and to get them to consider a different pattern (using literals). After all, _needing_ a builder is typically just a language smell.

Comment: Your criticism comes across as veiled. Why not be completely open and say what you mean in your answer - that you believe that object literals suffice?

Comment: Well, I do get a form of artistic freedom when I write here - do I not? The fact at least 4 people got it means that it might not be as problematic as you suggest - and now with these comments in place future readers will surely not mistake it.

Comment: An upvote counts as getting it? More likely people from the stackexchange JS chatroom piled in on the joke.

Comment: That's also a plausible way to explain it. Yes.

Comment: The builder pattern provides more than the object literal syntax. It provides a well-defined, fluent interface. It decouples the actual structure of the resulting object from the client code. In my trvial example, it is redundant. In real-world examples with complex object structures, it can make sense. So, whilst I might appreciate your humor (if it were not so misleading) I disagree with your opinion.

Comment: Right, and if you take an hierarchal object in that function and transform it - which is a _very_common pattern in JavaScript (virtually all libraries do that) you get just that. Also, the fact you _can_ make a builder with a fluent interface it's not actually a part of the pattern at all. I guess you're just going to have to disagree with my opinion, but I'm serious about this answer and I assure you it's not snark. Why builders in the first place? The problem a builder would solve simply does not manifest in a language with no constructor delegation and hierarchal literals.

Comment: I might add that my teeth grate at Java and the excesses of enterprise OO as much as anyone, and that I was aware that this so-called "builder" does not meet the "requirements" for the official GOF pattern. Doing so is a pragmatic simplification and indicates my view of patterns as tools rather than dogma.

Comment: As is indicated in the example code in my question: I want something that enables the *lazy* creation of a command to instantiate an object. I used the word "builder" because, my requirement encapsulates much of what the builder pattern enables (not all however), and that I was too lazy to find a better word. Given that, your answer does not meet my requirements. If I merely wanted to transform an object, then there would be no intellectual challenge.

Comment: In that case neither does the accepted answer since it creates the object in advance, if you want code for lazily creating an object through partial application than that's something I can help you with - but it has nothing to do with the name "builder pattern" and is really far from both your code and the code in the accepted answer.

Comment: Answer has been de-selected. Thank you for highlighting it.

Comment: Well, but that isn't very fair to the person who posted it - as your question never really states you're interested in lazy construction of objects anywhere. You can ask a new question if you'd like but I wouldn't consider editing and changing an existing one particularly fair.

Comment: Can you clarify the distance between the code in my answer and the true builder pattern?

Answer (score 5):

It is usual with a builder to be able to chain the calls together, so something like the below should do what you're after:

```
var builder = (function(){
    var obj = {};
    return {
        withFoo: function(foo){
             obj.foo = foo;
            return this;
        },
        withBar: function(bar){
             obj.bar = bar;
            return this;
        },
        build: function(){
            var rtn =  obj;   
            obj = {}; // clear so you can use builder again
            return rtn;
        }
    }    
})();

var result = builder.withFoo("foo")
                    .withBar("bar")
                    .build();
console.log(result); // { foo: 'foo' , bar: 'bar' }
```

Having said that, I like to have an *instance* of the builder, so in all honesty I prefer your original (except with `return this` to return the current instance of the builder from the methods). So I'd personally go with:

```
function Builder() {
    this.spec = {};
}

Builder.prototype.withFoo = function(value) {
    this.spec.foo = value;
    return this;
};

Builder.prototype.withBar = function(value) {
    this.spec.bar = value;
    return this;
};

Builder.prototype.build = function() {   

    return this.spec;
};

var result = new Builder()
                 .withFoo('foo value')
                 .withBar('foo value')
                 .build();
```

Note there is no need to clear out `spec` when calling`build` - a new instance of `Builder` will have a new instance of `spec`!

Comment: "Note there is no need to clear out spec when callingbuild - a new instance of Builder will have a new instance of spec!" It depends on the usage pattern. For something like a test suite, it may be useful to avoid having to repeatedly new-up a builder.#

Comment: @BenAston - Im not sure I follow, but OK. If I was testing this object the first thing I'd do ("Arrange") is to create a new instance of the thing im testing. Doing it that way specifically avoids one test from affecting the next.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to invoke code lazily is partial application and currying in particular.

Let's say you have a `Person` type and it looks like this:

```
function Person(name, lastName, age, height){
    
    return {
        name: name,
        lastName: lastName,
        age: age,
        height: height
    };
}

var pete = Person("Pete", "Doe", 40, 6.4);
```

What we really want it to do - is to be able to specify only some of those properties initially and some later:

```
var namedJoeDoe = Person("Joe", "Doe"); // won't work today
var tallJoe = namedJoeDoe(40, 8.6); // one object
var shortJoe = namedJoeDoe(40, 4.3);  // another object
```

We only create the object (and your real objects are probably larger at the very end. This is currying, and if we use [Ramda's `curry`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#curry) we can write it as such:

```
Person = R.curry(Person); // impl at src/curryN.js
```

We get exactly this functionality, quoting the docs:

> Returns a curried equivalent of the provided function. The curried function has two unusual capabilities. First, its arguments needn't be provided one at a time. If f is a ternary function and g is R.curry(f), the following are equivalent:
>
> - `g(1)(2)(3)`
> - `g(1)(2, 3)`
> - `g(1, 2)(3)`
> - `g(1, 2, 3)`

That is, only when you've supplied all properties for a person will an instance be created.

Comment: Thank you. Currying is the word I was looking for. The problem is that the client needs to be aware of the meaning of the specific curried invocation. Are you aware of a technique to mitigate this issue? Perhaps simply passing simple object literals as arguments with property names to identify the purpose of the value.